# Angular4 Routing Child redirect not working

Tags: angular, angular4-router

i build my angular4 routing like this:

```
{path: 'siteroot', component: SiteMessengerComponent},
{
    path: '', component: FrameDefaultComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'user/:userId', component: SiteUserprofileComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'home', component: SiteUserprofileHomeComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'about', component: SiteUserprofileHomeComponent,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, i do a profile, that is loaded inside of the FramedefaultComponent. Inside the profile i want some sub profile views. the default view need to loads the "home" view.

The problem is that i dont find anything at google that explain the same thing that i try to do. I want that when i open the profile with the url: /user/24 (24 is in this case the user id) then i want that he open direct the user/:userId/home. but what ever i try i get compiler errors.

What i did wrong?

Here is the site-userprofile.component.ts

```
export class SiteUserprofileComponent implements OnInit {
    users: Observable<User[]>;
    userId: number;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private userListService: UserListService) {
        this.users = this.userListService.users;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params) => this.userId = params.userId);

        this.userListService.get([new Filter({
                name: 'ids',
                value: this.userId
            }
        )], true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an empty path inside your `user/:userId` children.  Have the empty path redirect to your `home` path

```
{
    path: 'user/:userId',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'home',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'home', 
            component: SiteUserprofileHomeComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'about',
            component: SiteUserprofileHomeComponent,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ähh my Bad... I forgot to Renate to top "Home" to siteroot... I meaning I want to load the "Home" that is bestes inside the Profile :)

Comment: The above answer should be what you are looking for? Did it not work for you?

Comment: If there is not template for `SiteUserprofileComponent` and you're just redirecting to `SiteUserprofileHomeComponent` then there is not need for `SiteUserprofileComponent`.  Just pull the user details inside the `SiteUserprofileHomeComponent`.  With `component: SiteUserprofileComponent` removed. the above should function how you want.  I'll put together a working plnkr as well.

Comment: Thanks this works =) One more thing... Whats is about i am doing a profile "about" route and a site "about" route? the name is identical, so how i can explan the router later, wich "about" i want to open?

Comment: Not sure I understand,  you want to add a general `/about` route along with the `/user/:userId/about`?

Comment: exactly. i add now a präfix to about "user-about" but this sucks in the url: /user/40/user-about